# Spring Boot Lambda Mongo Configuration Issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have deployed a Spring boot lambda function and got the following error upon API invocation. But it works on the local machine. I'm wondering about the missing AWS configuration

Please refer to the error.

```
2022-12-31T01:42:59.669-06:00   07:42:59.669 INFO 8 --- [ main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@515fff35 from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-02.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-01.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}, ServerDescription{address=cluster0-shard-00-00.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   07:43:07.405 INFO 8 --- [.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-02.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   ... 4 common frames omitted

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00

Copy
07:43:07.405  INFO 8 --- [.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017
07:43:07.405 INFO 8 --- [.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.gu1ji.mongodb.net:27017

2022-12-31T01:43:07.405-06:00   com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to database `gu1ji.mongodb.net` from some client as mongoDB Compass ? connection is timing out!

Comment: Yes, it's working in local environment as well before deploying to a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed my lambda within the VPC without proper configurations. VPC configurations are not mandatory for the cloud function, hence I removed them.